# React Native | Firebase Messaging

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using firebase push notifications in my React native project. With the recent update (11.5.0), the application was no longer functional due to the changed functions. I also upgraded to 11.5.0. With the code I wrote below, it gives the following error on Android when buying FCM Token on IOS. What is the solution?

```
package.json

"@react-native-firebase/app": "^11.5.0",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^11.5.0",
"react-native-push-notification": "^7.3.1",
```

```
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

const fcmToken = await messaging().getToken()
console.log('fcm token ', fcmToken);
```

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

Try add `firebaseMessagingVersion = 21.1.0` in `buildscript` of your app/build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
  ext {
    ....
    firebaseMessagingVersion = "21.1.0"
  }
}
```